# Very simple Ruby GServer leaking memory

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks

I've got the following Ruby script:

```
class Server < GServer

  def initialize    
    super(10001)
  end


  def serve(io)
    while true
     io.puts `ps -o rss= -p #{$$}`.to_i
    end
  end

end

server = Server.new
server.start

while true
  sleep 10
end
```

When I open a connection to the server, it shows increasing memory usage over time, without me opening any new connections or doing anything at all.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a memory leak issue in GServer?

BTW: I tested it on MacOSX with Ruby 1.8.7 and on a Debian System with 1.9.2.

Comment: How much is it leaking on your system?

Comment: Right after starting it, the process has around 4kB, after 10 minutes its around 16kB

Comment: It appears to be storing the memory amount in io forever so maybe monitor this from the outside using top and see if there's a leak there. As it is, the leak is merely that you're putting that output into the output every time the server gets a chance to run.

Comment: @ChuckVose: I don't think so, because some times, it remains at the same memory amount for about a minute, and then it increases again. In that minute, there are about 20,000 IOs, so it does not seem to be IO related.

Comment: You're probably right, but I would still try doing the leak testing from outside for comparison. For what it's worth though the number does increase on my system as well. Also OS X 1.8.7 but at least you know you aren't crazy.

Comment: Well, I tried the same thing with a "sleep 1.0/1000.0" in the while true loop (that is, sampling the memory usage with ps, but not from within the script) and it still did show increasing memory usage. Maybde "ps" isn't suited for this purpose? Is there a better way to sample the memory usage of a process? Please let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

16kb doesn't necessarily mean a memory leak.  If you have a real memory leak it will go up and up to hundreds of MB's over time.  That being said you can look for memory leaks using mem-prof and valgrind.